# smack Plain SASL to jabberd

Tags: smack

I am using smack 4.2.1 and trying to connect to a ejabberd server.
The server uses plain SASL mechanism from auth.

I am able to authenticate if I use another library like babbler.
But with smack I have no luck.

I keep getting the exception below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder.Base64.encode(Base64.java:64)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder.Base64.encode(Base64.java:60)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:42)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism.authenticate(SASLMechanism.java:212)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism.authenticate(SASLMechanism.java:170)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:202)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:386)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:493)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:467)
```

My code is

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration c = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder().setHost("api.coredial.com")
            .setHostAddress(InetAddress.getByName("api.coredial.com")).setDebuggerEnabled(true).setPort(5222)

            .setXmppDomain(String.valueOf(JidCreate.bareFrom("api.coredial.com")))
            .setUsernameAndPassword(userName,password)


            .setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();


    XMPPTCPConnection con = new XMPPTCPConnection(c);


    // Connect to the server
    con.connect();
    //con.login();
    con.login(userName,password);
```

Any suggestion would be appricaited.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue after including the smack-java7 and smack-sals-javax dependency into my pom.xml.

I believe adding the jars seem to cause static initialisers to add the initialization necessary to enable plain sasl.

Comment: You really shouldn't add jars to your project in 2017. Use a build system which is able to consume Maven artifacts. Then you wouldn't wonder why only a part of smack is initialized.